# Search and replace a word in a string with an array

Tags: arrays, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I want to scan a paragraph and replace needles in that with another word. for example

```
$needles = array('head', 'limbs', 'trunk');
$to_replace = "this";
$haystack = "Main parts of human body is head, Limbs and Trunk";
```

Final out put needed

```
Main part of human body is this, this and this
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With preg_replace :

```
$needles = array('head', 'limbs', 'trunk');
$pattern = '/' . implode('|', $needles) . '/i';
$to_replace = "this";
$haystack = "Main parts of human body is head, Limbs and Trunk";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $to_replace, $haystack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP, you can try [`str_ireplace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

```php
$needles = array('head', 'limbs', 'trunk');
$to_replace = "this";
$haystack = "Main parts of human body is head, Limbs and Trunk";
echo str_ireplace($needles, $to_replace, $haystack); // prints "Main parts of human body is this, this and this"
```